# Enum active record clearance_level problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums

I have a users table with levels of authorization... (customer/vendor/admin) 
but i cant seem to save a new user with default set to 0 which would equal "customer" the error is saying "'0' is not a valid clearance_level" ?

Here is my user model

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    include Clearance::User
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :password, presence: true
    validates :password, confirmation: { case_sensitive: true }
    enum clearance_level: [:customer, :vendor, :admin]
  end
```

and this is my migration file... (i removed the column and added it again incase that solved it?)

```
  class ChangeClColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
      remove_column :users, :clearance_level
      add_column :users, :clearance_level, :integer, :default => 0

    end
  end
```

Also my schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "email", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", limit: 128, null: false
t.string "confirmation_token", limit: 128
t.string "remember_token", limit: 128, null: false
t.string "first_name"
t.string "last_name"
t.date "date_of_birth"
t.integer "clearance_level", default: 0
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email"
t.index ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are saving a string '0', not an integer 0. Everything you get from your params is a string. You have two options here: 1. convert it to an integer before assignment. 2. use the `enum` name and send "customer" from your form instead of "0". Both will save successfully.